# Bootstrap treeview performance issue

Tags: bootstrap-treeview

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) for showing a tree.

Does it have any functionality which will check all child nodes when parent node is checked?

Currently I can't find any way to do this.

To achieve this functionality I have written recursive function to find each node under root and check using `checkNode` function.

I see a performance issue when depth of the tree is more than 3 for around 150 nodes. On investigation I found `checkNode` function in `bootstrap-treeview.js` uses `render` each time node is checked, can anyone tell me the use of this `render` function?

Can we remove use of `render`?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with performance using a recursive solution as well, but I found a more efficient alternative. The call to `checkAll` is fast, even with large trees, because it only makes a single call to `render`, while a recursive implementation of this checking using `checkNode` will call `render` many times unnecessarily, as you pointed out.

I couldn't find this in the documentation, but I noticed that `checkNode` calls `forEachIdentifier` in its implementation, the same as `checkAll`, so you can actually pass in an array of nodes or nodeIds, instead of just a single nodeId, and it will only call `render` only once, after all the nodes are checked. The only difference for `checkAll` is that it specifically passes in all the nodeIds in the tree.

So you can just add some code in your event handler to generate the list of nodeIds for all nodes underneath the parent, by looking at the id of the last child node and building a range, then call `checkNode` once.

```
function onNodeChecked(event, node_data) {
    var first_index, last_index, last_node, nodes, range, i;
    nodes = node_data.nodes;
    if (nodes != null) {
      first_index = node_data.nodeId;
      last_node = nodes[nodes.length - 1];
      while (last_node.nodes != null) {
        nodes = last_node.nodes;
        last_node = nodes[nodes.length - 1];
      }
      last_index = last_node.nodeId;
      range = [];
      for (i = first_index; i <= last_index ; i++) {
        range.push(i);
      }
      return $('#tree').treeview('checkNode', [range, {silent: true}]);
    }
}
```

Edit: revised code to properly handle the case where the last child has children.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Edit bootstrap treeview js files.

find **toggleCheckedState** function and replace with below

```
Tree.prototype.toggleCheckedState = function (node, options) {
    if (!node) return;
    this.setCheckedState(node, !node.state.checked, options);
    if (node.nodes && !options.ignoreChildren) {
        $.each(node.nodes, $.proxy(function (index, node1) {
            this.toggleCheckedState(node1,_default.options);
        }, this));
    }
};
```